# Free disk alignment tool?

Tags: hard-drive, alignment

Knows anyone a free disk alignment tool for windows like the [paragon disk alignment tool](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/partition-alignment/)?

I'm not going to pay 30 dollar for this hopefully one time use case. But I could not find any good free alternative so far.

I need it to align the partitions on an old non-SSD drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Vista onwards will automatically align partitions correctly using the built in tools: [source](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_set_up_Windows_on_a_VERTEX#Windows_Vista)

That [OCZ page](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_set_up_Windows_on_a_VERTEX#Windows_Vista) also details the steps necessary to properly align the partitions on Windows XP.

GParted is a free tool that can also [align partitions correctly](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-specify-partition-alignment) and has a [LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php/) version that you can use.

In order to check the alignment you can check the accepted answer on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/132296/how-to-check-the-partition-alignment-on-an-ssd-drive).

Though, as you said you are using an old non-SSD drive, is the alignment really that important?

Comment: Yes, because it is related to this issue: http://superuser.com/questions/412691/asus-formula-i-ahci-crucial-ct256m4sd1-ssd-boot-issue I havent had the time yet to continue with it but I want to give it a try now soon. I want to know if it is correct that the controller fails to load all drives properly because of the wrong aligned SATA disk. I'm using Win7 btw and the disk its running on is indeed not correctly aligned. Guess its because I did not reformat it when I installed it because I wanted to keep the data partition on it besides the system partition.

Answer (score 2):

[MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) has a partition alignment feature and is free for personal use.